# Is it correct to afirm that philosophy had no begining?

Tags: logic, history-of-philosophy, semantics

According to wikipedia:

> Philosophy (from Greek φιλοσοφία, philosophia, literally "love of
>   wisdom"[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy)[2][3][4]) is the study of general and fundamental problems
>   concerning matters such as existence, knowledge, values, reason, mind,
>   and language.

Taking this semantic meaning philosophy seems  to be like a natural condition of human existence has explained in [metaphilosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy) even though philosophy as such was first identified by the Ancient Greeks.

Comment: You are speaking of "semantics": why ? If you mean the origin of the *term* philosophy*, the answer is obviously: No, it is not. The term philosophy has no use before Ancient Greece.

Comment: It depend how you define philosophy, and beginning. That is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'... it is owing to their wonder that men both now and at first began to philosophize' : Aristotle, Metaphysics, 982b (The Complete Works of Aristotle, II, ed. J. Barnes, Princeton : Princeton University Press, 1984, 1554).

If this is so, then presumably there is no datable starting point of wonder. It seems intrinsic to, or at least entirely typical of, the kind of beings we are to wonder at large.

The likely course of events is that in ancient thought, long before the Greeks, religious beliefs or tribal myths and legends produced the beginnings of abstract thought about the world, its origins and destiny or fate, and about 'the reason of things' (Grayling).

Such thought gradually crystallised into the philosophy we recognise in (say) the presocratics. There is no reason to believe that philosophy, first familiar in the West in the ideas and arguments of the ancient Greeks, was not flourishing at the same time or earlier in India and China.

**References**

Henri Frankfort, Before Philosophy: The Intellectual Adventure of Ancient Man, ISBN 10: 014020198X / ISBN 13: 9780140201987
Published by Penguin Books.

A.C. Grayling, The Reason of Things, ISBN 10: 0753817136 / ISBN 13: 9780753817131
Published by Phoenix, 2003